# How to explain decision tree algortihm in layman's terms?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, algorithms, decision-trees

I have a task at hand, where I have to explain *`decision tree`* algorithm to a person who has not much understanding of `machine learning`. I have been looking around, but find it difficult to explain the algorithm in layman's terms, so that a person will understand what is happening in the process.

What is the best way to describe the algorithm, possibly using some very simple basic example, so that the whole process of the algorithm is broken down to simple steps for understanding?

Answer (score 3):

I learn well by examples, so perhaps this will be helpful:

Lets say you are a resort considering your next advertizing campaign. You will be sending out 1,000 vouchers that give two *free* days at the resort, with the hope that the customer will decide to extend it to a full week (who want's a two day vacation?!).

You have a rather extensive database of customer data, including where they are from, income range, duration of stay(s) and money spent at each stay, number of children, marital status, and employment status (working, unemployed, retired). You would like to create a decision tree to help select the customers to send the vouchers to (specifically, those who will spend at least $200 per day and stay at least one week.

To create the tree, a computer will perform the following steps:

1. From the above list of customer data, find the property that best separates the customers into two groups.
2. Repeat step one for each of the above groups using the remaining properties.
3. In the end, you will have a tree where at each point, you can make one of two decisions. Following a path leads to a decision. The split points will be chosen to maximize the probability of a correct classification.

Answer (score 1):

A decision tree is a graph that uses a branching method to illustrate every possible outcome of a decision. Here each internal node represents a "test" on an attribute (e.g. whether a coin flip comes up heads or tails), each branch represents the outcome of the test and each leaf node represents a class label (decision taken after computing all attributes). The paths from root to leaf represents classification rules. This can be represented as graph. Now you can parse through the possible nodes and edges as per the condition rules (if condition1 and condition2 and condition3 then outcome.)

Wikipedia link itself has some great examples :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree

Do check these links also :

http://blog.echen.me/2011/03/14/laymans-introduction-to-random-forests/

http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/decision-tree

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar for Regression Tree. I came up with as very simple complete example; I wrote out tables of dependent and independent variables on the board. The trickiest part is to explain how the first split happens, (that it minimizes MSE of dependent variable within the sub-samples), being able to point to the table helps. And after that we do the same thing just for a sub problem.